# Chat with node.js always on top on all pages

Tags: node.js, chat

I am building a person to person chat using node.js in a php website (using zf)
I am wondering how facebook (for example) is doing to always have the footbar visible even when navigating from pages to pages.
I first thought they used ajax everywhere so the page is never realy reloaded but it appears not as you can use the browser back/forward buttons to navigate (and I don't realy see any ajax call in my browser developper tools). So, my second thought is that all facebook is build with a kind of node.js alternative so everything works with js sockets ?

Any idea how to do a similar system, to have my chat windows always visible even when navigating my website?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure they do not load actual page when you navigate within Facebook, but it is all JavaScript navigation that is available in newer browsers and documented at http://html5doctor.com/history-api/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history. That is why you get this "smooth" experience and the chat remains on screen even though you are moving from one page to another, back and forward.

Comment: Hum ok thanks, so it seems I have to recode most of my website to make what I want possible :/

Comment: Just to be sure, before I decide to spend weeks redoing what I have done :p
I need to make my application ajax full (plus html5 history api). So, most of my layout (except headers, footers, menus) will be created by javascript (I suppose javascript templates files containing html) and not sent from the server.
Am I correct ? It seems ugly to me to "design" most of my GUI in js files instead of proper html files

Comment: If you're making a web app like this, you might want to research http://angularjs.org/

Comment: @Tagazok, there are quite a few template engines out there. Probably AngularJS Max has mentioned worth trying. I have never used it though. You can also take a look at Dust LinkedIn version at http://linkedin.github.com/dustjs/